# Get Website Dedicated IP Address Using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I am Useing HttpWebRequest for communications. It is possible to get website ip address(dedicated ip) not server ip.
when i use Context.Request.ServerVariable("Remote_Addr") it return only server ip.
But I need website ip address.

For Example

There are 3 client's website send httpwebrequest to my site. Each have dedicated ip address.

My Website Receive that Request and perform some work and then response.

Example Coding Client Send HttpWebRequest:

```
Dim uri As New Uri("http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage.ashx?username=client1&password=123456")
If (uri.Scheme = uri.UriSchemeHttp) Then
    Dim wrequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
    wrequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
    Dim wresponse As HttpWebResponse = wrequest.GetResponse()     
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(wresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim tmp As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
wresponse.Close()  
End If
```

Example Coding For HttpHandler:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
 Dim remoteIP As String = context.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
 If remoteIP = "client1ip" Then
    Dim ref As String = Trim(context.Request.QueryString("username"))
    Dim number As String = Trim(context.Request.QueryString("password"))
   'do some work
Else
    context.Response.Write("Access Denied")
End If
```

End Sub

This is my example coding. Here **remoteIP** return hosting provider server ip but i need website ip address.

it is possible to get website ip address using httpcontext in httphandler.

Comment: Can you clarify.  You want to get the IP address that your client application is connecting to when you hit the domain name?

Comment: my clients are sending request to my site using httpwebrequest. so how can i find this request which client send to my site how can i predict thats way i want to get ip or domain name from httpwebrequest class. it is possible?

Comment: so you want to get the website and IP address of the client machine that is connecting to your site?

Comment: yes i want to get website name or website ip address.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for. It will do a DNS lookup on the hostname of the website, which should give you the IP Address that it is listening on.

```
string dnsHostname = "yourwebsite.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(dnsHostname);

foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
{
   Console.WriteLine(theaddress.ToString());
}
```

You will likely only need the first result of the array.

Comment: how can i get client website address from the httpwebrequest?

Comment: i need client website ip address or website name that is dnshostname? it is possible to get from httpwebrequest class

Comment: I'm sorry... I misunderstood what you were asking. When you said you were looking for the static ip of the website, I didn't understand that you were talking about a website that was connecting to your service. I think I would need more information as to what is happening here, my next thought would have been that Martin's answer below was correct, but it appears you've already mentioned that wasn't correct either

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said so far, the variables you're looking for are:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
Request.UserHostName
```

The issue you will be that you might not get a unique IP if they're using a proxy, but other than that, you should be able to get what you need from them.

Comment: I already try this but it return website visitor address. I use generic handler page to handle client website request. In httpcontext have request and response object using that i can able to get client (here client means client website) ip address. not visitor ip address.

Comment: you are not going to be able to get the vistor visiting another website, technically the only connection to your website is the website that is connecting to you, so unless they can pass the user's ip address, you will have no exposure to that

Answer (score 0):

After understanding your question more now...

I don't think you are going to be able to get the vistor this other website that is connecting to your site. Technically the only connection to your website is the website that is connecting to you, so unless they can pass the user's ip address, you will have no exposure to that